# An unwinding cable problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, rotational-dynamics, work

Suppose a light cable is wrapped around a solid cylinder with mass $M$ and radius $R$. The cylinder rotates with no friction about a stationary horizontal axis. The free end of the cable is attached to a block of mass $m$ at a height $h$ above the floor. We want to find the speed of the falling block when it hits the floor.

Without doing too much mechanics, I just want to confirm that I am not making any incorrect assumptions in my solution:

By conservation of energy applied to the block $m$, $K_f=W_{cable on block}+W_{gravity on block}=-W_{cable done on cylinder}+mgh$

and we calculate $W_{cable done on cylinder}$ using the momentum of intertia. I am unsure whether the assumption $W_{cable on block}=-W_{cable done on cylinder}$ is correct.

This setup does give the correct answer, but it may be flawed. I do know how to solve this with an alternate setup which gives the same equation (namely consider the system of the block and the cylinder), but I suspect my approach is wrong because $k_f$ should also equal the initial potential energy of the block, $mgh$, which means $W_{cable done on cylinder}=0$.

Comment: What is $W_{cabledoneoncylinder}$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

From conservation of energy you find

$$mgh = \frac12 m v^2 + \frac12 I \omega^2$$

And the relationship between $v$ and $\omega$: $v=\omega R$.

The result then follows.